# PHP - send HTTP Request and log the full response (headers + payload)

Tags: php, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I use this function to make my HTTP Requests and i successfully get the body of the Response:

```
function SendRequest($url, $method, $data, $headers){
    $context = stream_context_create(array
    (
        'http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => $headers,
            'content' => $data
        )
    ));

    return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
```

But i need a way to get the whole HTTP Response (including the headers)!
Both for debugging and practical reasons.

For example lets say i make a request to login webservice and in the response there is a session cookie. This way i cannot get it.

*Also if possible, it would be nice if there was a way to log the Requests for debbuging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to do it by using [$http_response_header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php).

```
function SendRequest($url, $method, $data, $headers) {
    $context = stream_context_create(array
    (
        'http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => $headers,
            //'content' => http_build_query($data)
            'content' => $data
        )
    ));

    $response_body = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    //var_dump($http_response_header);
    return array(
        'headers' => $http_response_header, 
        'body' => $response_body
    ); 
}
```

*$http_response_header will be created in the local scope

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [stream_get_meta_data()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-get-options.php) function.  For http streams, it will include the HTTP response headers and status line in the `wrapper_data`[2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#refsect1-context.http-notes)